# URL not rewriting correctly for subdirectories

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am using this code for url rewriting
What its not doing is  if there is directory  i want to go like [this](http://sample.com/folder/Dashboard)   its going to profile.php any idea how to do  hide extension php in subdirectory

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?username=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: not working  
The requested URL /Artist/Dashboard.php was not found on this server.
http://localhost/desi/Artist/Dashboard (trying this url)